# What should I plan for on a sea-to-summit ride on Mauna Kea, Hawaii?

Tags: climbing, planning

I've driven up to the visitor station but not up to the summit - what are the road conditions like beyond the visitor station, where can you refill water, and should I prepare for anything beyond a leg crushing day?

I'll be starting on Kona (west) side, in September, and am expecting about 6-7 hours of straight climbing.

Here's about all I know so far;

> **Mauna Kea, Hawaii, HI**
>
> This mostly paved climb is perhaps the largest
>   rideable climb in the world.  The first 34 miles are paved, then 5
>   miles often loose cinder gravel, and then 3 final miles of pavement. 
>   The first 28 miles up Saddle road from Hilo gains only 6600 feet at
>   modest grade, tapering off to almost flat in the saddle between Mauna
>   Loa and Mauna Kea.  Turning off onto Mauna Kea Access Road is a real
>   shocker, as you are now faced with sustained 17% grades at high
>   altitudes.  The Fiets index for this climb is off the charts at nearly
>   30.  It’s a combination of net gain and high altitude driving the high rating.  Like Haleakala, views are too good to describe with words. 
>   Many of the world’s most powerful telescopes are at this summit.

ref: http://www.northeastcycling.com/Favorite_Climbs.html

Thanks

Comment: I recommend going up to do a personal reconnaissance. At that altitude the consequences of getting it wrong can be serious, so I'd be cautious about taking advice from even such sensible people as us. A friend rode to the visitor station but not beyond.

Comment: @andy256 this is part one of that recon. :) elevation above sea level  will be tough to replicate since I live near Boston.

Comment: This [page](http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/info/vis/visiting-mauna-kea/visiting-the-summit.html) has contact details for the visitor center. I suggest a phone call :-) I'd love to hear how the ride goes!

Comment: Three things you should prepare with: newish brake pads for the descent, good lights, and warm clothes for the highest parts.  I haven't done this climb, but that's (incomplete) general advice for this type of attempt.

Comment: If you haven't already, read [this article](http://cyclingtips.com.au/2014/11/tackling-mauna-kea-the-worlds-biggest-climb/) by Norwegian blogger Martin Hoff

Comment: Don't plan on doing it in the winter. http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/info/vis/visiting-mauna-kea/winter-visits.html  Unless you know for sure there is water beyond VIS be prepared for no water.

Comment: @jurgemaister Thanks, that's a great article and the photography is just amazing.

Comment: @andy256 Were we awarded a badge I missed?  When did we get sensible?

Comment: @Chris No, but we have hats :-)

Comment: You can try riding up the Mt. Washington Auto Road, which has grades averaging 12% and up to 22% and goes up to 6000 feet, but this can only be done [twice a year during specific organized events](http://mtwashingtonautoroad.com/start-your-adventure/faqs/#Can%20I%20ride%20a%20bicycle%20on%20the%20Auto%20Road?). Not quite the same altitude but you may at least get a sense of whether you're ready for this ride.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks - I've thought about that and have had my eye on it for a few years but the timing has never worked out. I've logged 8k days @ Wachusett but will need to do a solid 10k+ to test the legs this spring.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this long post by Martin Hoff](http://cyclingtips.com.au/2014/11/tackling-mauna-kea-the-worlds-biggest-climb/) also indicated by [jurgemaister](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/3279/jurgemaister) in a comment tells you everything you need. You can find some more info in the comments on individual attempts people did of the segment [on strava](http://www.strava.com/segments/1504789). The main takeaways I got from the article are:

- You need two bikes (a road bike and a mountainbike) or a dirt-road suitable bike.
- You optimally have a support vehicle driving along with you for food/drinks/extra clothing/emergencies/the way down/nice pictures/the second bike.
- If support isn't an option you need to pack for a really long hard day in both winter and summer climates. Even if you are very fit. Use panniers mounted on your bike, a backpack carrying enough stuff will probably break you.
- Mauna Keau tops out at over 4K above sea level. How fit will you be up there? How used are you to high altitudes? Altitude sickness might be an issue, strenuous activity will certainly be very hard.
- You need low gearing for the steepest part. Install a mountainbike crank-set.
- If you take one bike you probably want knobbly tires on it.

Comment: This is way, way beyond me but you might consider dropping off a set of off-road wheels at the visitor centre and changing wheels (assuming you hire a car or something to recce it before the ride).  Maybe also a pannier with (some of) the cold-weather gear.  Or just a random bag for swapping out kit.  All in the interest of saving effort for the hardest bit.